# Problem with Tiled map chunk data after decompression

Tags: java, json, compression, tiled

I have a very specific use case for reading Tiled Map Editor data that doesn't require the entire (and often outdated) libtiled library.

JSON is my preferred format, since it's really easy to work with in Java. The code I have is working perfectly for raw, uncompressed chunk data that is base64 encoded. As soon as I change the setting in Tiled to gzip or zlib, I start to get completely invalid numbers after a couple of correct tile GID's are extracted from the base64 decoded string:

**RAW/UNCOMPRESSED (Correct data):**

```
Layer Name: Floor
Width, Height: 96,48 
Start X,Y: -80,-48
Encoding: base64
Compression: 
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,1099,1100,1101,691,692,693,694,695,696,697,1207,1208,700,701,
0,0,708,709,1243,1244,1245,713,714,1297,1298,1299,718,719,720,721,
```

**GZIP:**

```
Layer Name: Floor
Width, Height: 96,48 
Start X,Y: -80,-48
Encoding: base64
Compression: gzip
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,1099,1100,1101,45989871,-1074855936,701,45989871,-1074855936,701,45989871,-1074855936,701,45989871,-1074855936,
1213,79544303,-1074855936,701,45989871,0,0,-1074855936,701,45989871,-1074855936,1213,79544303,-1074855936,1213,45989871,
```

**ZLIB:**

```
Layer Name: Floor
Width, Height: 96,48 
Start X,Y: -80,-48
Encoding: base64
Compression: zlib
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,1099,1100,1101,45989871,-1074855936,701,45989871,-1074855936,701,45989871,-1074855936,701,45989871,-1074855936,
1213,79544303,-1074855936,701,45989871,0,0,-1074855936,701,45989871,-1074855936,1213,79544303,-1074855936,1213,45989871,
```

Working source code is here:
https://paste.ee/p/uRgnQ

Exported Raw, gzip and zlib JSON data are here:
https://paste.ee/p/lUsbq

Comment: It's hard to know where the bug is. Try writing some test for the code. Isolate the problem to a couple of specific functions: compress/decompress, read/write, encode/decode. Compression algorithms themselves will not be a problem, but most likely the code that passes data to them. Check that you read and write data correctly from the source. Check that data is saved with the expected encoding. If this isn't helpful, try narrowing down the question.

Answer (score 0):

eshiya in the Tiled forums got me pointed in the right direction to solve this.

First I changed the unzip method to use bytes instead, but that still returned the same result. I paid very close attention this time and noticed that the unzip method was returning only 526 bytes of the 1024 bytes I was expecting (16 x 16 x 4). This seemed to indicate improper handling of the unzipped data, so I googled around to find the proper way to unzip gzipped byte data.

Two quick source code changes later and it's working fine now!

First, have the method properly use only byte arrays, and an actual buffer:

```
    public static byte[] unzip(String b64) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64);
            GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = gis.read(buffer)) != -1){
                os.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            os.close();
            gis.close();
            return os.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new byte[1];
        }
    }
```

Next, change the return variable to the unzip call to match the method change:

```
                        case "gzip":
                            try {
                                decoded = unzip(chunkData);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            break;
```